# Constructor can access parent private properties in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, type-hinting

When dealing with inheritance in PHP I found some lack of knowledge, mainly about **constructors** and **private** properties.

Let's take this code as example:

```
<?php

class Module
{
    public $type;
    public function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
}

class BModule extends Module
{
}

class CModule extends BModule
{
}

class A
{
    private $module;
    public function __construct(Module $module)
    {
        echo 'Set module for '.__CLASS__.' to '.$module->type . PHP_EOL;
        echo "<br>";
        $this->module = $module;
    }

    public function getModule()
    {
        echo "I (as " . __CLASS__ . ") have a module of type " . $this->module->type;
        return $this->module->type;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
}


$m = new Module('base-module');
$bm = new BModule('bi-module');

echo "<br>--------A---------<br>";
$a = new A($m);
echo "<br>A is of type " . $a->getModule();
echo "<br>--------B---------<br>";
$b = new B($bm);
echo "<br>B is of type " . $b->getModule();
```

Some questions:

1. shouldn't B construction call the constructor in the context of B? (and so I would expect it to fail cause it didn't inherited the private property *$module*)

   - or PHP would simply call the A constructor, using/referencing methods and properties from A? (including the *private* ones)
2. I can pass to **$b** either a *Module* or a *BModule* object; this is because *BModule* is a child of *Module*. Is PHP checking some inheritance chain (checking the parents) of the passed object when verifying the type hinting?

   - so can I pass to the constructor either an object of type *Module* or *BModule* or *CModule*?

And this is another example:

```
<?php


class a
{
    private $a;
    protected $a_copy;

    public function __construct($a_value)
    {
        $this->a = $a_value;
        $this->a_copy = $this->a;
    }

    public function getA()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
    public function getCopyA()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

class b extends a
{
}


$a = new a('value for a');
$b = new b('value for b');
echo "<br>-----A-----<br>";
echo $a->getA()."<br>";
echo $a->getCopyA()."<br>";
echo "<br>-----B-----<br>";
echo $b->getA()." (I would expect to have no access to \$a)<br>";
echo $b->getCopyA()."<br>";
```

Being the property *$a* private, I **would expect to not be able to access it** or do anything with it from the class **b**.
It is a little bit non-sense for my actual understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected functionality, although B inherits all of the methods of A, they're not called in the context of B, they're called in the context of A. So the A constructor is called. This means that functions defined in A can access A's properties even when the object is extended. Methods defined in A cannot access properties of B however, which appears to be your understanding.

So to shortly answer your questions:

1. No, functions are always called in the context of where they are *defined*, not from where they are called.
2. PHP will check all the way down the inheritance chain to see if it's correct. Any child of a Class can be assumed to have the same functions. So if B extends A, You  can use either B or A as a parameter when it's type-hinted to A, but only use B if it's type-hinted to B

Comment: I'm a little confused. So if I have something simple like `class a { getClass() {return get_class($this);}}` and `class b extends a {}`, then calling `getClass()` on an instance of **b** wouldn't return **a**? (cause as we said the method is inherited and executed in the context of the parent **a**). Sorry for the bad formatting of the code, and sorry for eventual dumb questions.

Comment: That's correct, it would return B rather than A. This is because the _function_ is called in the context of A, but the actual _object_ that $this refers to is still of type B

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1: No, the context of the called method is where the method (in this case the constructor) is declared. If the context would be class `B` then anyone could break your class simply by extending it.

Take a look at this example:

```
class A
{
    private $module;
    public function __construct(Module $module)
    {
        echo 'Set module for '.__CLASS__.' to '.$module->type . PHP_EOL;
        echo "<br>";
        $this->module = $module;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(new Module()); // call the parent (which is A)
    }
}
```

This illustrates how the scope of `A::__construct()` is actually the `A` class.

Ad 2: Yes, each object that is an instance of sub class can be used in place of the super class. This is why you should write your classes so that they can be substituted when the static typing requires a super class. For more information on this subject see the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

As for the last example: again there is no code in sub class that would operate on private members of the super class. All code operates from within the super class context. So there is no problem here.

There would be a problem if you tried to overload methods of super class and use its private members like this:

```
class b extends a
{
    public function getA()
    {
        return $this->a . "_suffix"; // error
    }
}
```

In such case you must depend on the implementation of `getA()` method in the super class:

```
class b extends a
{
    public function getA()
    {
        return parent::getA() . "_suffix"; // ok, we are depending on the super class implementation
    }
}
```